# Is it possible to exit from a recursive function in javascript via an action outside of that function?

Tags: javascript, function, exit

I have a script (simplified in the example below) where a user action initiates a recursive function.

It is possible for the user to initiate a new action at a time when already initiated actions have not yet finished running.

But I would like to ensure that any new action **stops all previous actions**.

What actually happens at present (you can see this in the example below) is that no matter how many new actions the user initiates, each of the previously initated actions continues until it has finished.

I'd like to know if (in the example below) it's possible to start growing a new list when the previous list has only grown as far as 5 items and ensure the previous list grows no further.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var o = 0;

function addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber) {

    var listItems = orderedList.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    if (listItemNumber > 9) {
        return;
    }
    
    listItems[listItemNumber].classList.add('show');
    listItemNumber++;
    setTimeout(function(){addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber)}, 400);
}

function startRecursiveFunction() {
    
    var orderedList = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[o];
    var listItemNumber = 0;
    if (o < 7) {
        addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber);
    }
    o++;
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', startRecursiveFunction, false);
```

```css
p {
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}

ol {
display: inline-block;
}

li {
opacity: 0;
}

li.show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to trigger function (up to 7 times)</p>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter variable, which will be increased every time `startRecursiveFunction` is called. In the `setTimeout` callback, you check if the counter has changed, and if so, you stop recursion.

```js
var trigger = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var o = 0;
var fnId = 0;

function addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber) {

    var listItems = orderedList.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    if (listItemNumber > 9) {
        return;
    }
    
    listItems[listItemNumber].classList.add('show');
    listItemNumber++;

    var lastFnId = fnId;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (lastFnId === fnId) {
        addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber);
      }
    }, 400);
}

function startRecursiveFunction() {
    
    var orderedList = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[o];
    var listItemNumber = 0;
    if (o < 7) {
        fnId++;
        addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber);
    }
    o++;
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', startRecursiveFunction, false);
```

```css
p {
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}

ol {
display: inline-block;
}

li {
opacity: 0;
}

li.show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to trigger function</p>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks Michal - I've gone with a solution which is not exactly identical to yours above, but follows the same principle in that it passes to the inner function an ID number which is then repeatedly compared to the variable outside the inner function which may have been updated in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clearTimeout` to cancel the time out event that is scheduled.

Note the three changes to your code marked with `***`, which all deal with the new `timer` variable:

```js
var trigger = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var o = 0;
var timer; //***

function addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber) {

    var listItems = orderedList.getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    if (listItemNumber > 9) {
        return;
    }
    
    listItems[listItemNumber].classList.add('show');
    listItemNumber++;
    // ***
    timer = setTimeout(function(){addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber)}, 400);
}

function startRecursiveFunction() {
    
    var orderedList = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[o];
    var listItemNumber = 0;
    clearTimeout(timer); // ***
    if (o < 7) {
        addListItems(orderedList, listItemNumber);
    }
    o++;
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', startRecursiveFunction, false);
```

```css
p {
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}

ol {
display: inline-block;
}

li {
opacity: 0;
}

li.show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to trigger function (up to 7 times)</p>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ol>
```

However, I should add that this is not true recursion: the call stack does not keep growing with each call to `addListItems`, since the previous invocation will have already ended when the next one is initiated through the `setTimeout` event: the call stack is empty between such calls.

It it were true (synchronous) recursion, there would be nothing you could do with click events, since those event callbacks would not be called until after the recursion finishes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, @trincot. In advance of coming to StackOverflow for help, I tried a number of approaches using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, but could not get any to work successfully in the case of my (fairly complex) setup. Nevertheless, I recognise this would be a normal way to approach terminating repetitive processes early.